# Why variables that I export in bash script does not work on EC2?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services

When I create EC2 inst. I use bash script into user data where I export variable AWS credentials and then run the command to copy files from S3 bucket. But this command is not executed.

```
#! /bin/bash 
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=MYACCESSKEY
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=MYSECRETKEY
aws s3 cp s3://mys3bucket/ ./
```

How to fix it?

Comment: So is the command not being executed? Or is it being executed but giving an error because the variables aren't exported? Your title says one thing, your question says another thing. Did you check the cloud-init logs to see what happened? Why are you even doing it this way, instead of using an EC2 instance profile to provide the AWS credentials to the script?

Comment: @MarkB, cloud-init logs : fatal error: An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records. I want to try the way described above? Is it impossible?

Comment: It sounds like you aren't passing a valid key in the user data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is run on its own bash process which dies at the end of your script.

Exported variables are preserved only for the lifetime of your script and they are also visible from child processes of your script.